# In Fluent NHibernate, how do you map a Component list?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

how do you map a Component list in Nhibernate fluently?

```
  public class Registration : Entity
{
        public virtual IList<InsuranceInformation> InsuranceInformation { get; set; }
     }

public class InsuranceInformation
{
    public virtual Person Insured { get; set; }
    public virtual string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string InsuranceCompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual string InsuranceCompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual string PlanType { get; set; }
    public virtual string GroupNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual FamilyRelationships InsuredRelationshipToPatient { get; set; }
 }
```

Here Registration is an Entity and InsuranceInformation / Person are Components.

If I change InsuranceInformation to be a Entity, I can map it easily with FluentNH Automapper.  But when I change InsuranceInformation to a Component it throws a mapping exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Fluent NHibernate IDictionary with composite element mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522929/fluent-nhibernate-idictionary-with-composite-element-mapping) shows an example of mapping a dictionary of components:

```
HasMany<CategoryResource>(x => x._resources)
.AsMap<string>("LangCode")
.KeyColumn("EntityID")
.Table("CategoryResources")
.Component(x =>
    {
        x.Map(c => c.Name);
        x.Map(c => c.Description);
    })
.Cascade.All();
```

Hopefully that will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the Automapper you need to tell it that `InsuranceInformation` is a component by modifying your `IAutomappingConfiguration`. Override the `IsComponent` method and return `true` for your `InsuranceInformation` type.